# OSX: programmatically get uptime?

Tags: macos, uptime

Something similar to linux

```
cat /proc/uptime
```

which returns the uptime in seconds, and preferably not parsing uptime(1).

Comment: please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199631/convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds/48762631#4876263

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Uptime article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uptime) has an interesting lead:

> **Using sysctl**
>
> There is also a method of using sysctl
> to call the system's last boot
> time: $ sysctl kern.boottime
> kern.boottime: { sec = 1271934886,
> usec = 667779 } Thu Apr 22 12:14:46
> 2010

Which references [sysctl(8)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sysctl.8.html), which references [sysctl(3)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctl.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/sysctl).

Comment: and just in case any apple people see this, it sure would be nice to have this wrapped up in /proc!!

Comment: which is not the uptime. Uptime can be calculated from this, given that the system time has not been changed since boot and given that the system does not support any kind of suspend.

Answer (score 19):

Old question, I know, but I needed to do the same thing so I thought I'd post the code I'm using, which I got from http://cocoadev.com/wiki/FindingUptime

```
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

double uptime()
{
    struct timeval boottime;
    size_t len = sizeof(boottime);
    int mib[2] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_BOOTTIME };
    if( sysctl(mib, 2, &boottime, &len, NULL, 0) < 0 )
    {
        return -1.0;
    }
    time_t bsec = boottime.tv_sec, csec = time(NULL);

    return difftime(csec, bsec);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is trying to do this programmatically using `sysctl.h` and is expecting a string back like what you see in the command line, the returned value that I get is a 16 byte array, not a string:

`sysctlbyname("kern.boottime", value, &size, NULL, 0);`

An example for what gets put into `value` in hex starting from the [0] index:

a9 af c6 4e 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 28 be 92 55

The first 4 bytes (maybe the first 8, won't know until Jan 2012) is the epoch time in little endian byte order.

Answer (score 1):

correct way:

```
CFTimeInterval getSystemUptime(void)
{
    enum { NANOSECONDS_IN_SEC = 1000 * 1000 * 1000 };
    static double multiply = 0;
    if (multiply == 0)
    {
        mach_timebase_info_data_t s_timebase_info;
        kern_return_t result = mach_timebase_info(&s_timebase_info);
        assert(result == noErr);
        // multiply to get value in the nano seconds
        multiply = (double)s_timebase_info.numer / (double)s_timebase_info.denom;
        // multiply to get value in the seconds
        multiply /= NANOSECONDS_IN_SEC;
    }
    return mach_absolute_time() * multiply;
}
```

also you could use `CACurrentMediaTime()` from QuartzCore.framework (which has same code probably) - Available since OS X v10.5 and iOS 2.0

Comment: I suspect this is a better solution. I would also suggest using `mach_continuous_time()` (in place of `mach_absolute_time()`) if running macOS 10.12 or later.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Bleyddyn's answer (since it's 11 years and counting)...

I needed a small utility to print the uptime in seconds, so I took that code and slightly altered it to compile on modern macOS.

You can clone the [`luckman212/uptime_s`](https://github.com/luckman212/uptime_s) repo and run `./build.sh` to generate your own universal binary that will simply print the uptime in secs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `UpTime` declared in DriverServices.h.  I believe this is equivalent to another function `mach_absolute_time`.  Both seem to be undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the "sysctl kern.boottime" returns the seconds of the timestamp, not elapsed seconds..  Multiple calls do not increase the second count, but must be seconds from epoc of the boot date itself.

Comment: Just subtract the system's boot time from the current time to find out how long the system has been up.

Comment: @Gabe - which gives you wrong results if the system time has been modified since bootup.

Comment: FYI after trial and error, something like this solved my issue (slightly different than OP)

    date -r `sysctl -n kern.boottime | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/,//'` "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"

Comment: please have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199631/convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-seconds/48762631#4876263

Answer (score 0):

A simple Lua script to do exactly what you ask for:

```
local now=tonumber(io.popen("date +%s"):read())
local boottime=tonumber(io.popen("sysctl -n kern.boottime"):read():match("sec = (%d+)"))
local uptime=now-boottime
```