# /proc/uptime in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, uptime

I need the EXACT same output as Linux's "cat /proc/uptime".

For example, with /proc/uptime, you'd get

> 1884371.64 38646169.12

but with any Mac alternative, like "uptime", you'd get

> 20:25  up 20:26, 6 users, load averages: 3.19 2.82 2.76

I need it to be **exactly** like cat /proc/uptime, but on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it...

```
$sysctl -n kern.boottime | cut -c14-18
87988
```

Then I just converted that to readable format (don't remember how):

> 1 Days 00:26:28

Comment: Since I don't like to simply cut on hard boundaries (in case the layout of the output changes), I opted for the following: `while IFS=' =', read -d ',' key value; do eval "boot_time_$key='$value'" 2>/dev/null; done <<< $(sysctl -n kern.boottime | sed 's/^.*{//;s/}.*$/,/')`, you can then simply pull the value you need from `boot_time_sec`, and can convert it with something like `date -jf '%s' "$boot_time_sec"`

Comment: One small problem with this answer. Your `cut` is getting characters between fixed positions (from 14 to 18). This worked in your case because your system wasn't up for a long time, but for me this caused problems.

I changed the `cut` command to fix this small issue. `sysctl -n kern.boottime | cut -f4 -d' ' | cut -d',' -f1`.

Comment: If you want the uptime in *seconds* on Mac, you can use `ts_boot=\`sysctl -n kern.boottime | cut -d" " -f4 | cut -d"," -f1\`; ts_now=\`date +%s\`; echo $(($ts_now-$ts_boot));`

Answer (score 6):

There simply is no "/proc" directory on the Macintosh.

[On MacOS, you can do a command like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269321/osx-programmatically-get-uptime):

```
sysctl kern.boottime
```

and you'll get a response like:

```
kern.boottime: { sec = 1362633455, usec = 0 } Wed Mar  6 21:17:35 2013
```

Comment: So I should use 'cut' to remove the first x letters, which would be "kern.boottime: { sec = "?

I also need to remove the rest... I'm starting out on this kind of stuff.

Comment: there's also "`sysctl -n kern.boottime`", which gets rid of the "`kern.boottime`" bit.  The boottime variable is a struct, and I can't see an easy way built into the sysctl command to get the variables within the struct.

Answer (score 6):

```
boottime=`sysctl -n kern.boottime | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/,//g'`
unixtime=`date +%s`
timeAgo=$(($unixtime - $boottime))
uptime=`awk -v time=$timeAgo 'BEGIN { seconds = time % 60; minutes = int(time / 60 % 60); hours = int(time / 60 / 60 % 24); days = int(time / 60 / 60 / 24); printf("%.0f days, %.0f hours, %.0f minutes, %.0f seconds", days, hours, minutes, seconds); exit }'`
echo $uptime
```

Will return something like 
1 Day, 20 hours, 10 minutes, 55 seconds

Comment: I'm writing a shell script for macOS and need to get uptime in seconds. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I Do to get the the values instead of Cut method

```
sysctl kern.boottime | awk '{print $5}'
```

Where $5 is the Range of the string

Example

```
$1 Gives you "sysctl kern.boottime"
$2 Gives you "{"
$3 Gives you "sec"
```

from the String

```
kern.boottime: { sec = 1604030189, usec = 263821 } Fri Oct 30 09:26:29 2020
```