# Is there any alternative of gettickcount function in java which can give time since boot?

Tags: java, macos, boot, system-information

Is there any way to get time since system boot for mac os x in java?

In Visual studio we have gettickcount function but in java I am not able to get which function can do the same..

I dont want to implement it manually using timer that will be last option So is there any api function for that.

Comment: What feature are you attempting to offer the user?  And.. *"system boot time for mac os x in java swing"*  Why do you think 'system boot time' is in ***any*** way related to Swing?

Comment: how about parsing the `/Applications/Utilities/system.log` ?

Comment: It is not related to swing but as swing provided several api's to interact with os and i am currently working on swing so is there any way to get it in swing. Actually i want to know any timestamp which will accurate and will not change according to system time. using boot time i can calculate difference between previous stored boot time difference in my application and current boot time difference in my system and use it.

Comment: Is `uptime` available on Mac OS X? If so, maybe you could run that and parse the output.

Comment: I am editing my question again so that it can more clear to every one.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Instead of such a useless reply you can give me a direction sir.

Answer (score 1):

Via JNI you can have all API from OS

Comment: @BharatSharma maybe this one : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11676260/529543 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/11676260/529543, but you know the idea: JNI and you have everthing in Swing from OS

Comment: JNI idea i am having already . But again if i want time since system boot then it will depend on current system time which can be changed. So, time since boot will also change because it will be the difference between current time and last boot time.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no direct API for this. You can either execute a system utility program which will return you this value or can use JNI to achieve this.